# Creating table for placing images in LaTeX

Tags: image, data-visualization, tex

I am attempting to create a table for placing images in LaTeX. The first column is the (image) index, the second and third columns are images from different folder. For example, in the row with index = 1, the two images from the path `Images/1/1.png` and `Images/2/1.png` are placed in the second and third column locations. In the row with index = 2, the two images from the path `Images/1/2.png` and `Images/2/2.png` are placed in the second and third column locations. Just like this:

| Index | Image Frames Input | Image Frames Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `Images/1/1.png` | `Images/2/1.png` |
| 2 | `Images/1/2.png` | `Images/2/2.png` |

```
\newcounter{it}  \setcounter{it}{0}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\tabtoks\expandafter{\the\tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\tabtoks}

\resettabtoks
\newcounter{counterB}  \setcounter{counterB}{0}

\loop\ifnum\theit<6
    
    \addtabtoks{
    \addtocounter{counterB}{1} % increment
    \thecounterB
    &
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/1/\thecounterB.png}
\end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/2/\thecounterB.png}
\end{minipage}                              \\ \hline
    }
    \stepcounter{it}
\repeat

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
\hline
Index & Image Frames Input & Image Frames Output                \\ \hline
\printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\caption{The experimental results}\label{tbl:TheExperimentalResults}
\end{table}
```

**The output looks like this:**

[image: Output]

All suggestions are welcome.

### Reference:

- Big Buck Bunny

  https://peach.blender.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of row numbers manually, you could use the `nicematrix` package which keeps track of these numbers for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabular}[width=\textwidth,first-row,hvlines]{
  >{\arabic{iRow}}c
  >{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/1/\arabic{iRow}.png}}X
  >{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/2/\arabic{iRow}.png}}X
  }
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Index} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{Input} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Output}\\
& & \\
& & \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```